# Configuring and hosting WCF services in a Prism desktop application

Tags: c#, wpf, wcf, hosting, prism

My application is currently made up of 2 different solutions.

1) The Shell which contains all the WPF and front end logic
2) The BackEnd which contains all the WCF service implementations and NHibernate related data access. At the moment, there are 6 different WCF service contracts defined.

I currently have this working quite well in Visual Studio but need to consider the deployment options for when the application is installed on to a users PC. As far as I am aware there are numerous different ways of hosting WCF services -- in-process, as a Windows Service, in IIS. I am intrigued to know how people go about configuring this type of setup in a Prism application.

The nearest info I have found so far is from http://wcfguidanceforwpf.codeplex.com/releases/view/27987 but I don't think it is quite what I am looking for.

I would like to know :-

**a)** How and if you can allow the users the choice of different hosting strategies for WCF services?
**b)** All the examples I have seen show the ServiceHost opening and starting one service. Is this the recommended practice and I would have to create 6 Service hosts or could I start six WCF services in one ServiceHost?
**c)** If the WCF services are run in process for testing locally for example - do you use the bootstrapper in the Shell and open all 6 WCF services or is there some other place that this happens?
**d)** What strategies you use for configuring the endpoints or is it simply a case of modifying the app.config files?
**e)** If there are any decent references online or book that I have not managed to find that cover Prism desktop / WCF configuration?

Apologies for the amount of questions but usually I can piece together an idea of what I need to do from extensive Googling but on this occasion I cannot find anything other than the link above that seems to match what I need to know.

Any help with this on any question would be most appreciated.

Alex

Comment: WCF and WPF/Prism are mutually exclusive frameworks that do not affect one another. Furthermore you have two completely different products - the entire purpose of deploying services via WCF is to separate them from the consuming applications, thus they are hosted on a web server for all the desktop applications to communicate with. In short, your question makes no sense.

Answer (score 2):

Let me begin by saying that Prism and WCF are mutually exclusive frameworks, and the use of one does not preclude the use of the other in any way.

a) Why would you let them decide how to host their WCF service?  The easiest configuration is IIS hosting, which requires minimal setup.  One IIS web could host all of your six services, unless you needed a memory barrier by putting each one in a separate application pool.  Running the services in a Service Host is tantamount to writing an EXE (e.g. Windows Service) to serve the client.  A lot more work and configuration (from the Windows Service side, WCF configuration is the same, unless it conflicts with IIS by running on HTTP:80).  You have many options for the how, but you're using WCF, so I assume you have a client/server scenario.  If you have a Windows server, use IIS, imho.

b) You can run as many WCF services inside the same Service Host as you want, but if one fails, the whole EXE crashes.  That is why I suggest IIS application pools, which auto-restart on failure, and can be configured to run each service in a different application pool.

c) There are different strategies for where to put service integration code, depending on how your application is structured.  I would suggest writing a "Service" class for each of your WCF services and register each with your container, so you can use an ImportingConstructor on your view models that need any particular one.  You would initialize and register these classes in the bootloader.  At this point you may be asking yourself if you really needed 6 and maybe should consider consolidating into 1 WCF service.

d) I disagree with Sebastian here.  WCF configuration is simple if your service is simple.  The more complicated you need it to be, the more complex the configuration.  By default, you need very little configuration, and I would look at the WCF Service Configuration Editor tool included with Visual Studio to modify both your app.config and web.config, but don't get confused which one you are working on!  The simplest way to configure the client is to use the "Add Web Reference" and point to the URL on the server machine.  Remember that WCF allows you to configure multiple end points for the same service (an end point is a URL with a port and service name), and each endpoint can have one of many different protocols (I use basicHttpBinding, wsHttpBinding, or netTcpBinding, depending on my needs).  I suggest starting with wsHttpBinding, which is one of the easiest to debug.  Modifying the app.config or web.config by hand is going to get you in trouble, because one mistype and you're debugging for hours.  Stick to the editor.

e) You will not find a good reference on both Prism and WCF, because one does not affect the implementation of the other.  By encapsulating your WCF service code inside of a service class served up in Prism by the container, you remove any dependencies between Prism itself and the services, and don't cause yourself headaches later on by inadvertently coupling them together.  Later, you can inject your view models with a Moq service class that doesn't make calls to the actual service for testing purposes.  Prism has a very good CHM file that has all you need to know about Prism, WCF has great documentation on Microsoft's web site (no book required, unless you want to get fancy, like with that Windows Service).

Feel free to follow up.

Follow up #1:

As I use IIS to host my services, I haven't the experience to guide you on implementing a ServiceHost for multiple services.  However, IIS allows putting multiple services into the same application pool (which is basically a single instance of W3WP.exe running on your machine), so I am pretty sure it can be done.

Edit:  After reading the WCF Guidance for WPF you provided, I can see that you create one ServiceHost instance inside your EXE for **each** service you want to host.  So you'll need 6 ServiceHost instances, and manage them separately in the EXE code.

Factoring your services is a matter of design.  You chose to have one service per domain class.  If I did that in my application, there'd be over 100 services.  Instead, I chose a to implement a command pattern which allow me to make requests for the objects I want, regardless of type, and it returns them to me in one, clean interface.

I am confident you will not find guidance on accomplishing your design between Prism and WCF in any book.  You may find some in blogs, however, here is what I suggest:

Encapsulate your WCF service creation and operations inside of a class (e.g. DataAccessService) that can be injected into your view models through dependency injection (see ImportingConstructor attribute).  Use the eventaggregator service to publish events from your DataAccessService if errors (or other notifiable events) occur, and handle them in your view model.  Don't create cohesion between your view models or views and the WCF services by calling between them directly, as that will violate both SRP as well as prevent the ability to test the view models without touching your web services (an external dependency).

Comment: With regards to b) and c) my issue arises because I have a WCF service for Products, one for Customers, one for Orders, one for Addresses etc. I cannot see how you can implement those in 1 WCF service. Also, I cannot see how you could run one service host containing 6 WCF services in all the sample ServiceHost code I can see. For e) I was looking for some guidance on how to make the service calls production ready and return faults from the WCF service back to the client when using MVVM.

Comment: @lostinwpf you are thoroughly confused my friend - your application architecture inside WPF (Prism, MVVM, whatever) has nothing to do with how your service works... try building one piece at a time... build and deploy your WCF service on a web server, run unit tests against it and Fiddler2. When satisfied... open your WPF solution and write its back end to talk to the WCF endpoints... there is a black and white line between each of your solutions

Comment: @Bahru +1 for simply trying to explain...

Answer (score 0):

**a)** For the "if": sure, why not? For the "how": Write different modules that deploy your services to IIS or Windows Services or Console Hosts and let the user choose which one to run.

**b)** One Service per host but multiple endpoints with different bindings are possible.

**c)** In process means that they start when you start your application? Then I would go for the bootstrapper.

**d)** There is nothing simple about configuring WCF via app.config. The tooling in Visual Studio is puny and the number of knobs and dials is legion. Using code for configuration at least gives you Intellisense support.

**e)** I don't think that this is a very common combination so I would not bet that there is any literature out there. But for any questions regarding WCF I would recommend reading [Programming WCF Services](http://www.amazon.de/Programming-WCF-Services-Mastering-AppFabric/dp/0596805489/ref=sr_1_1?ie=UTF8&qid=1329483073&sr=8-1) by Juval Lowy. I think the code samples also contain a WinFormsHost for WCF service which might be another option for your "where do I host services" problem.